# Rails 6 - Redirected to service-worker.js after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service-worker, ruby-on-rails-6

I've added PWA functionality to my rails 6.0.2.1 application, also using devise, following this tutorial, with the controller method: https://onrails.blog/2019/01/08/easy-pwas-the-rails-way/

Now whenever I login with any user, I get redirected directly to the service worker file itself (http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js) instead of the root path.
The file itself is copy-pasted from the tutorial, and I followed it step by step. 
No matter how hard I looked, I couldn't find what was causing the redirect to the file after login or sign up.

Update: it seems to have to do with self.find_first_by_auth_conditions, the code from devise allowing log in with username instead of email.

Thanks in advance! I'm really stuck...

Log file output on sign in:
[image: log file output when signing in]

```
# Service Worker Routes
get '/service-worker.js' => "service_worker#service_worker"
get '/manifest.json' => "service_worker#manifest"

# application.js
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js', { scope: './' })
    .then(function(reg) {
      console.log('[Companion]', 'Service worker registered!');
      console.log(reg);
    });
}
```

```
# service_worker.js.erb
var CACHE_VERSION = 'v1';
var CACHE_NAME = CACHE_VERSION + ':sw-cache-';

function onInstall(event) {
 console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Installing!", event);
 event.waitUntil(
   caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function prefill(cache) {
     return cache.addAll([
       '<%= asset_pack_path 'application.js' %>',
       '<%= asset_pack_path 'application.css' %>',
     ]);
   })
 );
}

function onActivate(event) {
 console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Activating!", event);
 event.waitUntil(
   caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
     return Promise.all(
       cacheNames.filter(function(cacheName) {
         // Return true if you want to remove this cache,
         // but remember that caches are shared across
         // the whole origin
         return cacheName.indexOf(CACHE_VERSION) !== 0;
       }).map(function(cacheName) {
         return caches.delete(cacheName);
       })
     );
   })
 );
}

// Borrowed from https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp
function onFetch(event) {
 event.respondWith(
   // try to return untouched request from network first
   fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
     // if it fails, try to return request from the cache
     return caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
       if (response) {
         return response;
       }
       // if not found in cache, return default offline content for navigate requests
       if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' ||
         (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
         console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Fetching offline content", event);
         return caches.match('/offline.html');
       }
     })
   })
 );
}

self.addEventListener('install', onInstall);
self.addEventListener('activate', onActivate);
self.addEventListener('fetch', onFetch);
```

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
   conditions = warden_conditions.dup
   if login = conditions.delete(:login)
     where(conditions.to_h).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first // row 35 referenced in log file
   elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
     where(conditions.to_h).first
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just add a respond_to in your controller action and it will solve it (for me it did at lease).
Your ServiceWorkerController will look like this

```
class ServiceWorkerController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :service_worker

  def service_worker
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end

  def manifest
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, and in my case the issue was I was storing the previous URL to redirect back to after login and the service-worker was gumming that up. This is specific to my app, but I fixed by adding `|service` as seen below (the only change).

application_controller.rb

```
# Redirect the user back to the last page they were on before accessing the sign in/out
before_action :store_location

private

def store_location
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users|service/
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || root_path
end

def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
  request.referrer
end
```